# unix sytem-access

Tags: unix, permissions

I have the permissions below for the directory `V`, created by the owner `a`. Now, according to the properties, the associated group should also be able to read write and execute in the directory.

Does that mean that all the users who belong to the group `b` have access? So if I log in as the user `c`, who is a member of group b, will I have rwx rights?

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 a b 4096 Mar 10 17:16 V
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um, yes. That's what [group permissions](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/help/faq/permissions.html) are. The way you have it set up now is:

```
d rwx rwx r-x
- --- --- ---
|  |   |   |------> Everybody can read(r) and execute(x)
|  |   |
|  |   |----------> All group members can read(r), write(w) and execute(x) 
|  |
|  |--------------> Owner can read(r), write(w) and execute(x) 
|
|-----------------> it is a directory
```

Comment: @Suresh: If you don't want that behavior, have a look at _Access Control Lists_ (http://users.suse.com/~agruen/acl/chapter/fs_acl-en.pdf). But note, that those must be supported by you file system and must be enabled with a mount option.